# ATmega64a float to IEEE-754 unexpected result

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754, atmega, atmelstudio

I am trying to convert a float to an IEEE-754 Hex representation. The following code works on my Mac.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

union Data {
    int i;
    float f;
};


int main() {
    float var = 502.7;
    union Data value;
    value.f = var;
    printf("%08X\n", value.i);
    return 0;
}
```

This is giving me the expected result of 43FB599A.

When I run this code on an ATmega64a I am getting 0000599A not 04A2599A as originally posted which was a mistake.

The first two bytes are not expected but the final two bytes seem correct?

Any ideas?

---

As mentioned in the accepted answer the I was assuming that `int` was 4 bytes. I was writing the code on my mac and sending it to someone that was downloading it to an 8-bit ATmega64a. On the ATmega64a `int` is 2 bytes, not 4. I changed `int` to `unsigned long` which is 4 bytes on the ATmega64a.

In addition, I had to add a length sub-specifier of `l` to the format given to printf. This is because when given a specifier of `x`, printf uses a type of `unsigned int` to interpret the corresponding argument. Adding the length sub-specifier of `l` tells printf to use the type of `unsigned long` to interpret the corresponding argument.

Using only the length sub-specifier of `l` and not changing the variable `i` to `unsigned long` was causing printf to grab some extra bytes and output `04A2599A` as originally posted. I, of course, needed to change the type of `i` to `unsigned long` as well as use the length sub-specifier of `l`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: At least make it `unsigned int i`

Comment: Also please decide- it  is running on ATMega64 or for your Mac? What is the size of `int` on the target system?

Comment: Perhaps `04A2599A` is correct - depends on `float` encoding.  Step 1 would be to report the size of `float`,  `int`, `union Data`.

Comment: user1757006, Try and report  `printf("%a\n", var);`

Comment: What is the output of `#include <stdio.h>` / `#include <float.h>` / `#define p(x) printf(#x " = %d.\n", x)` / `int main(void) { p(FLT_RADIX); p(FLT_MANT_DIG); p(FLT_MIN_EXP); p(FLT_MAX_EXP); }`? What does the compiler documentation say about the floating-point format?

Comment: Read the datasheet and application notes and learn the sizes of the types.  A ATMega64 is not a computer.

Comment: user1757006, I suspect code was not properly compiled.  What is the command used to compile and link?

Comment: also 502.7 is a double literal. You need to use the f prefix to get a float: `float var = 502.7f`

Comment: The edits are unsatisfying. Given 16-bit `int`, `printf("%08X\n", value.i);` would generally print “599A” or some other 16-bit value, not “04A25599A”. Technically, the mismatch between `value.i` having type `int` and `%08X` expecting `unsigned int` results in behavior not defined by the C standard, but print “04A25599A” is not a common response to that by most C implementations. So it seems likely something else was occurring, and the information in the question is inadequate to say what, and so the question is not useful for future readers or to keep on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Eric Postpischil, I have edited the post again. Hopefully, this explains in more detail. "04A2599A" is a mistake. It should have been "0000599A". I got the first value when messing about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This processor is an 8 bit one which mean size of `int` is most likely 2 byte not 4 as your code assume.

Try to use `uint32_t` rather then `int` if you can.

Comment: If `int` was 2 -byte, output of `04A2599A` hard to explain.  If output was `0000599A`, sure.

Comment: Undeniably it is strange, but would worth a try to see what happens.

Comment: I think user1757006 has [left the building](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_has_left_the_building).

Comment: Hehe. Seems like, but hope he came back. I am curious what could be the cause.

Comment: So do I.  I suspect 1) `atmega` uses an alternate encoding 2) code lacks true FP math which messes up linking without FP lib 3) cockpit error.

Comment: So does this fixed it @user1757006 ?

Comment: Eraklon, I edited my post to reflect it but you were correct that I was assuming 4 bytes when int was 2 bytes. I used unsigned long instead which was 4 bytes. I also had to tweak the printf format specifier.